# Can we make setcookie in PHP reflected immediately in the current page?

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
<?php
    $cookie_name = "android_webview_communicate_cookie";
    $original_value = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    setcookie("android_webview_communicate_cookie", "this-is-set-by-Web");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $changed_value = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    echo "Original Cookie '" . $original_value . "'<br>";
    echo "Changed Cookie '" . $changed_value . "'<br>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

After running it, the `changed_value` displayed is the same as the `original_value` still.

Apparently seems like this is intended, as per https://www.php.net/setcookie

```
Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array.
```

My question is, is there a way to get it still loaded and viewed within the same view through the cookie (or do we need to use another variable to store it for that purpose?)

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191669/understanding-cookies-in-php

Comment: Thanks for that. I have changed my question to reflect the need.

Comment: Echoing values from $_COOKIE will reflect what the browser sent in its request. Since you’ve just set the cookie value, the effect won’t be seen until the browser makes another request. Maybe you want to use sessions?